# How to put my function in to class.Beginner

Tags: python, function

I have a Json function below need to construct a class having two function, How my second function will "know" that the `data` which is response from first function

```
def results():
        json_request = request.get_json()
        data = json.loads(json.dumps(json_request))
        return Response(data, mimetype='xml/html')
```

My pseudo-code is below:

```
class Myjson():
     def function_one():
            json_request = request.get_json()
            data = json.loads(json.dumps(json_request))
     def function_two():
           return Response(data, mimetype='xml/html')
```

Comment: what is the meaning of this line ? `How my second function will "know" that the data which is response from first function`. Do you want to check the first function is called or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to save your `data` as a property of the underlying `self` object of your class, e.g.:

```
class MyJson():
    def func1(self):
        self.data = ...
    def func2(self):
        return Response(self.data, ...)


x = MyJson()
x.func1()
y = x.func2()
```

Note that it is a good programming practice not to introduce new class attributes outside the constructor, so in practice you may want to add to the `__init__()` method something to initialize `self.data`, e.g.:

```
class MyJson():
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None
    def func1(self):
        self.data = ...
    def func2(self):
        return Response(self.data, ...)
```

---

## EDIT

(To address the request for a more reputable source.)

Essentially, all the elements can be found in the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) on the [chapter dedicated to classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

Of particular relevance to this question are:

- [the discussion on scopes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#scopes-and-namespaces-example)
- [the introduction of the class objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects)
- [the discussion on class and instance variables](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables)
- [some parts of the random remarks (especially at the end)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks)

Comment: @Maws I have added some sources. I hope this is now more clear and authoritative enough.